# Python - list of tuples converted to string list

Tags: python

I have a tuple list of university names and I'm trying to get it to store each university name as a string in a list. I have tried the following code. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

```py
def convertTuple(tup):
    str = ''
    for item in tup:
        str = str + item
    return str

main():

school = convertTuple(schoolName)

print(school)




schoolName = [('Carthage',), ('Clarkson',), ('F&M',), ('GMU',), ('Georgia_Tech',), ('IIT',), ('Kenyon',), ('MIT',), ('McDaniel',), ('Michigan_State',), ('NIU',), ('Oklahoma_State',), ('Penn_State',), ('Princeton',), ('Purdue',), ('Radford',), ('Ramapo',), ('Randolph_Macon',), ('Rowan',), ('Tarleton',), ('TCU',), ('Texas_State',), ('Tulane',), ('UMASS_Lowell',), ('University_Of_Alabama',), ('UC_Berkeley',), ('UC_Riverside',), ('Maine',), ('UMBC',), ('UNO',), ('South_Alabama',), ('South_Carolina',), ('UT_Austin',), ('Toronto',), ('University_Of_Washington',), ('Ursinus',), ('Washington_State',), ('Wisconsin',)]
```

Comment: Is `main():` supposed to be `def main():`? Where do you call it? The indentation is messed up.

Comment: side note: do not use `str` as a variable name. It shadows the built-in `str` class.

Answer (score 2):

You're not accessing the elements in the tuples. The school name is `item[0]`.

You're also concatenating the names into a string, not creating a list. Use a list comprehension to create a list.

```
def convertTuple(tuples: list) -> list:
    return [item[0] for item in tuples]
```

Comment: is there a way in this approach to store each school name into a separate element in a list

Comment: `return [item[0] for item in tuples]`. But your code is concatenating them, not putting them into a list.

Comment: or `[item for item, in tuples]`

Comment: @S.B Yeah, I really dislike that syntax for 1-element tuples, it's too easy to miss the `,`. `item[0]` is only 2 more characters and is much clearer.

Comment: right ! compelling...

Comment: With this approach, can you pull each element of the list in a for loop and just have each element as a string

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

you have to collect the string which is in the tuples

```
def convertTuple(tup):
    listOfSchoolName = []
    for item in tup:
        listOfSchoolName.append(item[0])

    return listOfSchoolName
schoolName = [('Carthage',), ('Clarkson',), ('F&M',), ('GMU',), ('Georgia_Tech',), ('IIT',), ('Kenyon',), ('MIT',), ('McDaniel',), ('Michigan_State',), ('NIU',), ('Oklahoma_State',), ('Penn_State',), ('Princeton',), ('Purdue',), ('Radford',), ('Ramapo',), ('Randolph_Macon',), ('Rowan',), ('Tarleton',), ('TCU',), ('Texas_State',), ('Tulane',), ('UMASS_Lowell',), ('University_Of_Alabama',), ('UC_Berkeley',), ('UC_Riverside',), ('Maine',), ('UMBC',), ('UNO',), ('South_Alabama',), ('South_Carolina',), ('UT_Austin',), ('Toronto',), ('University_Of_Washington',), ('Ursinus',), ('Washington_State',), ('Wisconsin',)]

school = convertTuple(schoolName)

print(school)
```